# targeting multiple elements with same attributes in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, loops, getattribute

I'm trying to target all `a` tags with the 'data-caption' attribute.

I tried achieving this by doing:

first grabbing all the `a` tags

```
  let links = document.querySelectorAll('a');
```

and then attempting to collect their attributes

```
 links.getAttribute('data-caption');
```

I get an error when I try logging the attributes saying "getAttribute" is not a function.

I tried giving one `a` tag an id and then targeting that specific link by doing:

```
let link = document.getElementById('link').getAttribute('data-caption');
```

and when I logged my link variable, the attribute was shown. Which is what I need but for all of my links.

My plan was to first target all the links and grab their attributes and then create a loop to be able to manipulate those attributes / display them.

here's some of my html showing my `a` tags for reference

```
<a id="link" href="photos/01.jpg" data-caption="I love hay bales. Took this snap on a drive through the countryside past some straw fields.">
     <img src="photos/thumbnails/01.jpg" alt="Hay Bales">
</a>

<a href="photos/02.jpg" data-caption="The lake was so calm today. We had a great view of the snow on the mountains from here.">
     <img src="photos/thumbnails/02.jpg" alt="Lake">
</a>

<a href="photos/03.jpg" data-caption="I hiked to the top of the mountain and got this picture of the canyon and trees below.">
    <img src="photos/thumbnails/03.jpg" alt="Canyon">
</a>
```

if anyone can please help / point me in the right direction, thank you!!!!

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll("a[data-caption]")` - will get all anchor tags with a data-caption attribute. It returns an array of the elements, so you'd loop over it and use getAttribute to read the value on each entry.

Comment: thank you, I got it ! this answers my question, thanks a lot! @LukeBriggs

Answer (score 0):

[`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) returns a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList), unlike [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) which returns the first element matching the selector. To get all anchor elements with the `data-caption` attribute, you have to iterate through it.

```js
let links = [...document.querySelectorAll('a')].filter(e => e.hasAttribute('data-caption'))
console.log(links);
```

```html
<a id="link" href="photos/01.jpg" data-caption="I love hay bales. Took this snap on a drive through the countryside past some straw fields.">
     <img src="photos/thumbnails/01.jpg" alt="Hay Bales">
</a>

<a href="photos/02.jpg" data-caption="The lake was so calm today. We had a great view of the snow on the mountains from here.">
     <img src="photos/thumbnails/02.jpg" alt="Lake">
</a>

<a href="photos/03.jpg" data-caption="I hiked to the top of the mountain and got this picture of the canyon and trees below.">
    <img src="photos/thumbnails/03.jpg" alt="Canyon">
</a>
```

You can avoid having to iterate through the list by simply using the `a[data-caption]` selector that selects all anchor tags with the `data-caption` attribute:

```js
let links = document.querySelectorAll('a[data-caption]');
console.log(links);
```

```html
<a id="link" href="photos/01.jpg" data-caption="I love hay bales. Took this snap on a drive through the countryside past some straw fields.">
     <img src="photos/thumbnails/01.jpg" alt="Hay Bales">
</a>

<a href="photos/02.jpg" data-caption="The lake was so calm today. We had a great view of the snow on the mountains from here.">
     <img src="photos/thumbnails/02.jpg" alt="Lake">
</a>

<a href="photos/03.jpg" data-caption="I hiked to the top of the mountain and got this picture of the canyon and trees below.">
    <img src="photos/thumbnails/03.jpg" alt="Canyon">
</a>
```